# Windows 8 customer preview, choose what to keep?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I'm trying to update Windows 8 from developer preview to customer preview. But I've got a question about 'Choose what to keep.' Actually, there is only one option which is Nothing. So, I'm wondering if I chose Nothing, I would lose other installed applicaions including Visual Studio or only Windows related applications. Before going on, I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Microsoft noticed on installation, any non release (alpha/beta/preview) versions are "not upgradable". Your `Windows` folder will be renamed to `Windows.old`, so you owe to reinstall all programs to achieve old functionality.

I don't remember, if `Program Files` renamed. Seems to me, that it not be deleted, however programs will not to be registered in new installation of Consumer Preview.

BTW, there is already `Release Preview`, however it is still not release...